# PHP parsing table/array string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Hello Stack Overflow,
  This is my first post and I have a problem I need to parse this text and turn it into an array (its from a database).

```
"TableToKeyValues"
{
    "inventory"
    {
        "slot2"
        {
            "amount"        "10"
            "item"      "wood_plank"
        }
        "slot1"
        {
            "amount"        "10"
            "item"      "metal"
        }
        "slot3"
        {
            "amount"        "10"
            "item"      "plastic"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks rtm516.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out how to do it by formatting it into json useing str_replace alot of times.

```
$inv = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $inv);
$inv = str_replace('}', '},', $inv);
$inv = str_replace('"       "', '":"', $inv);
$inv = str_replace('"           "', '","', $inv);
$inv = str_replace('"       {', '":{', $inv);
$inv = str_replace('"   {', '":{', $inv);
$inv = str_replace('"{', '":{', $inv);
$inv = trim(preg_replace('/\t+/', '', $inv));
$inv = str_replace('},}', '}}', $inv);
$inv = str_replace('},},', '}}', $inv);
$inv = str_replace('"TableToKeyValues":', '', $inv);
$inv = json_decode($inv, true);
```

Edit: $inv is the value from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that to be converted into `array` use `json_decode`

```
$arr = json_decode($dataComingFromDBHERE, true);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I thought it's a json. Where did the data coming from? Before inserting in the database.

Comment: A game called garrys mod using the lua function [util.TableToKeyValues](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/util/TableToKeyValues)